# Facebook problem: cant get user id into iframe without authorization

Tags: php, facebook, parameters

I have a facebook page with an iframe app.

I want it to be able to work in the same way as http://www.facebook.com/pepsi
With the following user journey.

1. User goes app tab on my page.
2. User is prompted with a page, partial content, that invites to click the like button
3. User clicks like and is shown full content.

all this is done without the client needing to login or authenticate.

My problem is that facebook is not passing me the user id.

I have tried 
`var_dump($_REQUEST);`
and
`var_dump($fb->fb_params);`
to see if user id is there but nothing.

I dont think php sdk 3.0 or oauth works for signed_request

Can someone tell me how I get the user id from facebook without login?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the user grants your application permission, the signed request will not contain their user id. See the docs for [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

> If the user has not authorized your application, your application will
> only be passed a subset of the above information.

This includes the `user` object (although it'd be nice if Facebook specifically mentioned what data is or is not passed for unauthorized users - I banged my head against the wall for a bit trying to figure this out.)

That being said, you don't need a user to be authorized in order to "like-gate" a page.

Comment: Thanks Arms, I will take a look at that, I thought I needed user_id for like gate.  Doing a lot of head scratching at the moment.  I will look at link you sent.

Comment: Just got my like gate working. First step was knowing it was called a like gate (Cheers @Arms).
I found this tutorial http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php on how to set this up.

One thing that I had wrong - In my app settings I had my canvas url and tab url pointing to the index.php. this seems to be why I was seeing a blank signed_request.

To fix as per above tutorial, I created a new php file, called tab.php and put in the tab setting. Low and behold, I'm now getting signed_request parameters such as likes.

cheers